# How to fix my Node.js syntax with ESlint?

Tags: node.js, eslint, visual-studio-code

I added couple of lines to check for errors on my REST API(POST method).
Lines 39-60

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', (req, res, next) => {
    pino(req,res);
    req.log.info('pino output');
    try {
      req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, (e, results) => {
        if (e) return next(e)
        res.send(results.ops)     
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof CustomError) {
        return res.status(err.status).send({
            error: err.code,
            description: err.message,
        }) else {
          console.error(err);
          return res.status(500).send({
            error: 'GENERIC',
            description: 'Something went wrong!!!',
        })
    }
  }
}   
})
```

When I run

```
eslint --fix index.js

/home/miki/restwitherrors/index.js
  46:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token catch

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

If I try in VSCode`,Shift+ALt+.` and choose `Fix all detected spelling errors`

output is

```
<semantic> TypeScript Server Error (3.8.3)
Cannot read property 'groups' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'groups' of null
    at DiagnosticIDDecorator.UndecorateFix (/home/miki/.vscode/extensions/manuth.eslint-language-service-1.0.1/node_modules/typescript-eslint-plugin/lib/Diagnostics/DiagnosticIDDecorator.js:65:92)
    at DiagnosticIDDecorator.UndecorateCombinedFix (/home/miki/.vscode

/extensions/manuth.eslint-language-service-1.0.1/node_modules/typescript-eslint-plugin/lib/Diagnostics/DiagnosticIDDecorator.js:75:109)
    at /home/miki/.vscode/extensions/manuth.eslint-language-service-1.0.1/node_modules/typescript-eslint-plugin/lib/Plugin.js:397:45
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (/home/miki/.vscode/extensions/manuth.eslint-language-service-1.0.1/node_modules/typescript-eslint-plugin/lib/Interception/Interceptor.js:100:34)
    at IOSession.Session.getCombinedCodeFix (tsserver.js:145760:56)
    at Session.handlers.ts.createMapFromTemplate._a.<computed> (tsserver.js:144516:61)
    at tsserver.js:146003:88
    at IOSession.Session.executeWithRequestId (tsserver.js:145994:28)
    at IOSession.Session.executeCommand (tsserver.js:146003:33)
    at IOSession.Session.onMessage (tsserver.js:146027:35)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (tsserver.js:147342:27)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:316:10)
    at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:461:12)
    at Socket.ondata (readline.js:172:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
```

How to get more info? How to fix syntax automatically?
I am adding my .eslinter.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should close your function `insert` before that you open your `catch`